# why chrome not act in <object> tag

Tags: html, object, pdf

in my application ,I have two button , button_1 and button_2 .  By button_1 , I send a query to server for getting a PDF file and then get it and show in a DIV named div1 in a  tag . By button_2 I send another query for getting a table and it is received successfully and show in another div named div2. for optimizing app , i use a flag that by selecting button_1 or button_2 , cause the query is sent for first time  and in second time and more no query is sent and div1 or div2 only appear . when use firefox no problem i encounter but by using chrome , by switching button_1 to button_2 and then button_1 , div1 does not show PDF file and it seems div1 hide . div2 has no problem and only div1 that contains PDF file has problem . it is appreciated if giude me . many thanks .

Comment: Please don't ask the duplicate question. (your question is the possible duplicates of various other questions).

Answer (score 0):

Use an **Iframe Tag** instead of object tag, as the object tag will be deprecated.

Because

1-object tags do not reliably work cross-browser.

2-Object Tag is Deprecated. Not for use in new websites.

**Syntax Of Iframe tag:**

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials"></iframe>
```

**Tips While using iframe Tag:**

**Tip 1:** Use CSS to style the iframe.

**Tip 2:** It is a good practice to always include a title attribute for the *iframe*. This is used by screen readers to read out what the content of the *iframe* is.

### When Should You Choose IFrames?

1- Provides the security you need.

2- Doesn’t block rendering.

Hope It may help.

Comment: i used iframe but problem  not be solved . Result is the same as object tag . any idea?

Comment: @saman if you share the code that would be helpful to track the bug. kindly edit the post.

Comment: I confused . when I select some chrome tab( 5 tab) and then return to my app , pdf file appear . no important what tab , only by selecting 5 different page tab (pages that is open in chrome) , when i select my app page tab , i can see pdf file. is it any setting in chrome that i should make?

Comment: @saman I have no idea since doesn't have access to your code.